# Material UI: Nest Menu Items Fail to Display

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I am using Material UI with React and am unable to get the submenu to display. Clicking on `Browse` in the top level menu simply closes the menu. Pressing Enter while hovering on it does the same. Pressing the right arrow key does nothing.

```
class TopNav extends React.Component {
  state = {
    anchorElement : null
  };

  handleClick = event => {
    this.setState({ anchorElement : event.currentTarget })
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ anchorElement : null })
  };


  render() {
    const {classes} = this.props;
    const {anchorElement} = this.state;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <AppBar position='static' className={ classes.root }>
          <OuterContainer>
            <IconButton
              className={ classes.menuButton }
              onClick={this.handleClick}
            >
              <FaBars size='1.5rem' />
            </IconButton>

            <Menu
              anchorEl={anchorElement}
              open={Boolean(anchorElement)}
              onClose={this.handleClose}
            >
              <MenuItem
                onClick={this.handleClose}
              >Home</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem
                onClick={this.handleClose}
                checked={true}
                menuItems={[
                  <MenuItem>Pet Rocks</MenuItem>,
                  <MenuItem>Support Rocks</MenuItem>
                ]}
              >Browse</MenuItem>
            </Menu>
          <...removed>
```

I've also tried using ListItem in place of MenuItem. The styling is worse and there is no change to the menu simply closing instead of displaying the submenu.

I also tried using nestedItems in place of the menuItems prop. No change to anything.

Anyone know what could be the problem?

I briefly read that a touch version of this library has a problem with premature closing, not sure if that is a potential issue here but i thought I'd note it.

```
// package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.2",
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "react-icons": "^3.4.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5",
    "styled-components": "^4.1.3"
  },,
  "devDependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.11"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`MenuItem`](https://material-ui.com/api/menu-item/) does not have a `menuItems` property for doing nested menus, so I would expect Browse and Home to behave exactly the same (which I think is what you are seeing).

[AppDrawerNavItem](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/docs/src/modules/components/AppDrawerNavItem.js) is the component used for the items in the navigation drawer in the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/). It uses [Collapse](https://material-ui.com/api/collapse/) for the nested items. You should be able to model off its approach to do nested MenuItems.

Here's a portion of the `AppDrawerNavItem` code with some comments added by me:

```
    if (href) {
      // This is the leaf item case, so the ListItem acts as a link to the href provided.
      return (
        <ListItem className={classes.itemLeaf} disableGutters {...other}>
          <Button
            component={props => (
              <Link naked activeClassName={classes.active} href={href} {...props} />
            )}
            className={clsx(classes.buttonLeaf, `depth-${depth}`)}
            disableRipple
            onClick={onClick}
            style={style}
          >
            {title}
          </Button>
        </ListItem>
      );
    }
    // This is the case of a parent of nested items.
    // Clicking on this toggles the `open` state which opens/closes the Collapse
    // which would contain the nested items.
    return (
      <ListItem className={classes.item} disableGutters {...other}>
        <Button
          classes={{
            root: classes.button,
            label: openImmediately ? 'algolia-lvl0' : '',
          }}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          style={style}
        >
          {title}
        </Button>
        <Collapse in={this.state.open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
          {children}
        </Collapse>
      </ListItem>
    );
  }
```